# AR App to play different videos depending on ARImageAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm creating an AR application for iOS to detect images on a cube (--> 6 different images to be recognised). When ever one image is detected a video should be played - a different video for each different image (for image 1 Video 1 should be played...).

My problem is I don't have any idea how to track which image is currently tracked and based on this which video to play

Right now the app tracks the different images but always plays the same video (video "1".mp4)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

    if let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ARImages", bundle: Bundle.main) {
        configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 6
    }
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor, 
          let fileUrlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp4") else {
        return
    }
    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrlString))
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoItem)
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

    player.play()
    ...
}
```

How can I identify the current ImageAnchor and link the related video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give ARReferenceImage a name so one way would be to give the image and the associated video-file the same name.

```
guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
             let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
             let fileUrlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp4") else {
    return
}

let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrlString))
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoItem)
let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

player.play()
```